# App crash when click Cancel AlertView

Tags: ios, crash, alert

Here is my code when i click button Add:

```
self.btnAddCard = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
self.btnAddCard.frame = CGRectMake(50, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - self.tabbarHeight - self.navigationHeight - 20, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - 100, 44);
[self.btnAddCard setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnAddCard setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255 green:171.0/255 blue:6.0/255 alpha:1.0]];
[self.btnAddCard addTarget:self action:@selector(addNewCard) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.btnAddCard.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
self.btnAddCard.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.btnAddCard];



- (void) addNewCard {
    if(self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 || self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hey" message:@"I don't support " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

When i click OK button, then i click button Add again, app is crashed.

The error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x6000000c)

I tried using UIAlertController, it's OK. 
I comment line [alertView show], app isn't crashed.
Anyone know the insult?

I test on iphone 5 9.2 version.

Comment: Please also post the crash message.

Comment: I've updated my question :D

Comment: The code you posted looks alright, the problem is not here. Could you post the whole thing?

Comment: I think something wrong when the alert is dismissed.

Comment: Try to enable zombies and check the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIAlertController,UIAlertView was deprecated from iOS9.

Comment: But i want to support for iOS 7.0

Comment: Either you can check for version and use accordingly or you should refer this https://github.com/BayPhillips/compatible-alert-controller.This will work for  iOS7 and above.